# How to Invisible Action Bar but not Back button too I need back button but not action bar in Android Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles, back-button

I have tried different way to invisible action bar but my back button also becomes invisible which I don't want please tell me how can I do it.
This is my pic where I wanna back button on left upper corner [image: This is my pic where I wanna back button on left upper corner]

Here is my style code:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Here is my java code:

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
       //actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
       actionBar.hide();
```

Comment: Did you try #00000000 as primary color? (and not hiding the ActionBar)

Comment: yes its giving me white action bar which I don't want

Comment: add a custom view for the back button that will help